# finding minimum number of rectangular pieces in a rectangular chocolate bar, with a rule

Tags: c, algorithm, dynamic-programming, rectangles

I'm having trouble with my school homework. I have a chocolate bar that consists of either black, white or black & white (mixed) squares. I'm supposed to divide it in two groups, one that has only white or black&white pieces and the other that has only black or black&white pieces. Dividing the chocolate bar means cracking it either horizontally or vertically along the line that separates individual squares.

Given a layout of a chocolate bar, I am to find an optimal division which separates dark and white cubes and results in the smallest possible number of pieces, the chocolate bar being not bigger than 50x50 squares.

The chocolate bar is defined on the standard input like this:
first line consists of two integers M (number of rows in chocolate bar) and N (no. of columns), then there M columns each consisting of N characters symbolizing individual squares (0-black, 1-white, 2-mixed)

Some examples of an optimal division, their inputs respectively (correct outputs are 3 and 7):

[image: Some examples of an optimal division]

```
3 3
1 1 2
1 2 0
2 0 0

4 4
0 1 1 1
1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0
2 0 0 0
```

My problem is that I managed to work out a solution, but the algorithm I'm using isn't fast enough, if the chocolate bar is big like this for example:

```
40 40
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 2 1 2 1 2 0 0 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 2 2 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 2 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 1 2 2 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 2 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 2 1 2 1 0 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 2 0 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 2 2 1 2 0 1 2 2 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 2 2 1 2 0 0 0 0 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 1 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 1 2 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 2 0 0 2 2 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 2 0 1 1 1 2 1 2 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 2 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 2 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 1 0
0 0 0 2 1 1 2 2 0 1 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 2 2 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 2 0
0 0 0 2 2 2 1 1 0 0 1 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 1 1 2 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 2 1 2 2 1 1 0 2 1 2 1 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 2 1 0 1 2 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 2 1 1 1 2 1 2 0 0 1 2 1 2 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 1 1 2 2 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 0 0 1 1 1 2 2 1 2 2 2 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 1 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 1 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 2
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 2 1 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2 2 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

then it takes 10 seconds for my program to solve it (correct solution for that one is 126 and I should be able to solve it in under 2 seconds!)

My algorithm works roughly with some minor optimization like this: iterate through all possible lines where it's possible to cut and then recursively do the same for the 2 newly emerged rectangles, if they cannot be divided anymore, then return 1.

The function after it iterates trough all the possible cuts always returns the minimum, once the minimum is found then store it and if I'd happen to need to solve this rectangle again then just return the value.

I thought that maybe If I happen to have already solved a particular rectangle and now I need to solve one that is one row or column bigger or smaller, then I could somehow use the solution I already have for that one and use it for the new one. But I really don't know how would i implement such a feature.
Right now my algorithm treats it like a completely new unsolved rectangle.

My code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int M, N;
unsigned int ****pieces; ////already solved rectangles, the value of pieces[y0][x0][y1][x1] is the optimal number of pieces in which the particular rectangle(that has upperleft corner in [x0,y0] and bottomright corner in[x1,y1]) can be divided
int ****checked;
unsigned int inf;

unsigned int minbreaks(int mat[M][N], unsigned int starti, unsigned int startj, unsigned int maxi, unsigned int maxj) {
    if (pieces[starti][startj][maxi][maxj] != 0) {
        return pieces[starti][startj][maxi][maxj];
    } else {
        unsigned int vbreaks[maxj - 1];
        unsigned int hbreaks[maxi - 1];
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < maxj - 1; i++) {
            vbreaks[i] = inf;
        }
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < maxi - 1; i++) {
            hbreaks[i] = inf;
        }
        unsigned int currentmin = inf;

        for (unsigned int i = starti; i < maxi; i++) {
            for (unsigned int j = startj; j < maxj - 1; j++) {
                if (mat[i][j] != 2) {
                    for (unsigned int k = startj + 1; k < maxj; k++) {
                        if (vbreaks[k - 1] == inf) {
                            for (unsigned int z = starti; z < maxi; z++) {
                                if (!checked[i][j][z][k]) {
                                    if (mat[z][k] != 2 && mat[i][j] != mat[z][k]) {
                                        vbreaks[k - 1] = minbreaks(mat, starti, startj, maxi, k) + minbreaks(mat, starti, k, maxi, maxj);
                                        if (vbreaks[k - 1] < currentmin) {
                                            currentmin = vbreaks[k - 1];
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    checked[i][j][z][k] = 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (unsigned int i = starti; i < maxi - 1; i++) {
            for (unsigned int j = startj; j < maxj; j++) {
                if (mat[i][j] != 2) {
                    for (unsigned int k = starti + 1; k < maxi; k++) {
                        if (hbreaks[k - 1] == inf) {
                            for (unsigned int z = startj; z < maxj; z++) {
                                if (!checked[i][j][k][z]) {
                                    if (mat[k][z] != 2 && mat[i][j] != mat[k][z]) {
                                        hbreaks[k - 1] = minbreaks(mat, starti, startj, k, maxj) + minbreaks(mat, k, startj, maxi, maxj);
                                        if (hbreaks[k - 1] < currentmin) {
                                            currentmin = hbreaks[k - 1];
                                        }
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    checked[i][j][k][z] = 1;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        if (currentmin == inf) {
            currentmin = 1;
        }
        pieces[starti][startj][maxi][maxj] = currentmin;
        return currentmin;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *file = stdin;
    fscanf(file, "%u %u", &M, &N);
    int mat[M][N];
    pieces = malloc(sizeof (unsigned int***)*M);
    checked = malloc(sizeof (int***)*M);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < M; i++) {//initialize the pieces,checked and mat arrays.
        pieces[i] = malloc(sizeof (unsigned int**)*N);
        checked[i] = malloc(sizeof (int**)*N);
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            int x;
            fscanf(file, "%d", &x);
            mat[i][j] = x;
            pieces[i][j] = malloc(sizeof (unsigned int*)*(M + 1));
            checked[i][j] = malloc(sizeof (int*)*M);
            for (unsigned int y = i; y < M + 1; y++) {
                pieces[i][j][y] = malloc(sizeof (unsigned int)*(N + 1));
                for (unsigned int x = j; x < N + 1; x++) {
                    pieces[i][j][y][x] = 0;
                }
            }
            for (unsigned int y = 0; y < M; y++) {
                checked[i][j][y] = malloc(sizeof (int)*N);
                for (unsigned int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
                    checked[i][j][y][x] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    inf = M * N + 1; //number one bigger than maximal theoretically possible number of divisions
    unsigned int result = minbreaks(mat, 0, 0, M, N);
    printf("%u\n", result);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

So anybody has any idea for improvements?

Comment: so many `*`-s..

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s86-Z-CbaHA might help

Comment: With for-loops nested four deep, no wonder it takes so long!  Edit: Do I also see a recursive call at the deepest level of those loops?

Comment: Also, should this be on the code review exchange?

Comment: @ChristianGibbons well I hope it should, I'm kind of new in asking questions here

Comment: @JohnDoe I was referring to this exchange: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ChristianGibbons ohh alright, didn't know about this site, so should I delete this question and move it there?

Comment: @JohnDoe I myself am not certain.  I think usually a question will be flagged to be moved.

Comment: There is an option "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network"  but sadly [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) isn't one of its targets.

Comment: If you solved the problem: well done. But your program is a four-star program. Even the [three star programmer](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer) invites comments to simplify, because more stars are not generally considered to be better.

Comment: [FYI](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46876996)

Comment: @Funk I'm not really sure how is that got to do anything with my problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because improvement of working code belongs in CodeReview.StackExchange.com

Comment: @Prune It is okay to recommend the OP post on CR but in the future, please don't use Code Review as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *too broad*, *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see the section **What you should not do** in [this answer to _A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users_](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: @SamOnela: Thanks!  Obviously, this is new to me.My closure vote was common SO practice when I first joined both sites -- and shouldn't have been, I think.

Comment: No worries - I had done it too

Comment: Can we have a scenario where we break off a part without splitting it all the way? Imagine a black "L" shape with the rest being white -- would we be obliged to break up the black "L" shape or can we somehow split off just the white rectangle?

Comment: @גלעדברקן I don't think it's possible to get an L shape, you can only break a rectangular chocolate bar all the way either horizontally or vertically, and then you get two new pieces that are both rectangles too

Comment: @JohnDoe oh, cool, that makes it easier.

Comment: @גלעדברקן if you think so xD

Comment: *"I thought that maybe If I happen to have already solved a particular rectangle and now I need to solve one that is one row or column bigger or smaller, then I could somehow use the solution I already have for that one and use it for the new one."* Just want to let you know that isn't necessary. You've got all the right concepts: break horizontally, break vertically, solve the smaller rectangles recursively, keeping track of the answers for rectangles already solved. You just need to clean up your code.

Comment: @user3386109 well I got rid of the warnings, but my main problem is that my algorithm isn't simply fast enough to solve the 40x40 input in under 2 seconds, I don't think cleaning up the code more solves that.

Comment: You have nested loops of depth **four** and a recursive call inside. They don't seem to do anything sensible. You need nested loops of depth **one** (i.e. no nesting at all) and two recursive calls inside them. You can break an `n×m` bar `m-1` ways horizontally **or** `n-1` ways vertically. That's `n-1+m-1` ways to break the bar. For each break you solve two smaller problems. Done.

Comment: @n.m. well I'm checking whether the current chocolate bar needs to be broken in that particular part in those nested loops

Comment: "well I'm checking whether the current chocolate bar needs to be broken" Why? Here's an algorithm: `solve (bar): if bar is uniform return 1; else return minimum_of (each way to make (bar = bar1 + bar2): solve(bar1) + solve(bar2))`. How did you manage to stuff four nested loops in there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [algorithm to divide black and white chocolate bar with least amount of breaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48038034/algorithm-to-divide-black-and-white-chocolate-bar-with-least-amount-of-breaks)

Comment: Please, stop posting our homeworks: https://cw.felk.cvut.cz/courses/a4b33alg/task.php?task=chocolate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everybody who helped me, my mistake was that in those nested loops I tried to avoid some unnecessary breaks, like this for example

```
1 1  -> 1 | 1
1 1     1 | 1
1 1     1 | 1
```

thinking it would speed up the runtime but the correct approach was just simply breaking the chocolate bar always everywhere possible.
Anyway for anyone interested here is my working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

unsigned int M, N;
unsigned int ****pieces; ////already solved rectangles, the value of pieces[y0][x0][y1][x1] is the optimal number of pieces in which the particular rectangle(that has upperleft corner in [x0,y0] and bottomright corner in[x1,y1]) can be divided
unsigned int inf;

int isOneColor(int mat[M][N], unsigned int starti, unsigned int startj, unsigned int maxi, unsigned int maxj) {
    int c = 2;
    for (unsigned int i = starti; i < maxi; i++) {
        for (unsigned int j = startj; j < maxj; j++) {
            if (c == 2) {
                if (mat[i][j] != 2) {
                    c = mat[i][j];
                }
            } else if (c != mat[i][j] && mat[i][j] != 2) {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

unsigned int minbreaks(int mat[M][N], unsigned int starti, unsigned int startj, unsigned int maxi, unsigned int maxj) {
    if (pieces[starti][startj][maxi][maxj] != 0) {
        return pieces[starti][startj][maxi][maxj];
    } else if (isOneColor(mat, starti, startj, maxi, maxj)) {
        return pieces[starti][startj][maxi][maxj] = 1;
    } else {
        unsigned int currentmin = inf;

        for (unsigned int j = startj; j < maxj - 1; j++) {
            unsigned int c = minbreaks(mat, starti, startj, maxi, j + 1) + minbreaks(mat, starti, j + 1, maxi, maxj);
            if (c < currentmin) {
                currentmin = c;
            }
        }
        for (unsigned int i = starti; i < maxi - 1; i++) {
            unsigned int c = minbreaks(mat, starti, startj, i + 1, maxj) + minbreaks(mat, i + 1, startj, maxi, maxj);
            if (c < currentmin) {
                currentmin = c;
            }
        }

        pieces[starti][startj][maxi][maxj] = currentmin;
        return currentmin;
    }
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *file = stdin;
    //FILE *file = fopen("inputfile", "r");
    fscanf(file, "%u %u", &M, &N);
    int mat[M][N];
    pieces = malloc(sizeof (unsigned int***)*M);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        pieces[i] = malloc(sizeof (unsigned int**)*N);
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            int x;
            fscanf(file, "%d", &x);
            mat[i][j] = x;
            pieces[i][j] = malloc(sizeof (unsigned int*)*(M + 1));
            for (unsigned int y = i; y < M + 1; y++) {
                pieces[i][j][y] = malloc(sizeof (unsigned int)*(N + 1));
                for (unsigned int x = j; x < N + 1; x++) {
                    pieces[i][j][y][x] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    inf = M * N + 1; //number that is bigger by one than maximal theoretically possible number of divisions
    unsigned int result = minbreaks(mat, 0, 0, M, N);
    printf("%u\n", result);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For any arbitrary rectangle, we can know if it contains either no white or no black pieces in `O(1)` time, with `O(M * N)` preprocessing of matrix prefix-sums for white and black separately (count 1 for each piece).

We can store potential horizontal and vertical split points separately in two k-d trees for `O(log(|splitPoints|) + k)` retrieval for an arbitrary rectangle, again preprocessing the entire input.

After that, a general recursive algorithm could look like:

```
f(tl, br):
  if storedSolution(tl, br):
    return storedSolution(tl, br)

  else if isValid(tl, br):
    return setStoredSolution(tl, br, 0)

  best = Infinity

  for p in vSplitPoints(tl, br):
    best = min(
      best,
      1 +
      f(tl, (p.x-1, br.y)) +
      f((p.x, tl.y), br)
    )

  for p in hSplitPoints(tl, br):
    best = min(
      best,
      1 +
      f(tl, (br.x, p.y-1)) +
      f((tl.x, p.y), br)
    )

  return setStoredSolution(tl, br, best)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a dynamic programming approach to this, but it won't be cheap either. You need to fill in a load of tables giving, for each size and position of rectangle within the main square, the minimum number of divisions necessary to divide up that smaller rectangle fully.

For a rectangle of size 1x1 then answer is 0.

For a rectangle of size AxB look and see if all of its cells are uniform enough that the answer is 0 for that rectangle. If so, fine. If not try all possible horizontal and vertical divisions. Each of these divisions gives you two smaller rectangles. If you work out the answers for all rectangles of size A-1xB and smaller and size AxB-1 and smaller before you try and work out the answers for rectangles of size AxB you all ready know the answers for the two smaller rectangles. So for each possible division, add up the answers for the two smaller rectangles and add one to get the cost for that division. Chose the division that gives you the smallest cost and that gives you the answer for your current AxB rectangle.

Working out the answers for all smaller rectangles before larger rectangles, the very last answer you work out gives you the optimum number of divisions for the full square. The easiest way to work out what the best division is is to keep a little extra information for each rectangle, recording what the best division found was.

For an NxN square there are O(N^4) rectangles - any two points in the square define a rectangle as opposite corners. A rectangle of size O(N)xO(N) has O(N) possible divisions so you have something like an O(N^5) algorithm, or O(N^2.5) if N is the input size since an NxN square has input data of size O(N^2).

(You could also do something very like this by taking your original code and storing the results from calls to minBreaks() so that if minBreaks() is called more than once with the same arguments it simply returns the stored answer instead of recalculating it with yet more recursive calls to minBreaks()).

Comment: actually my minBreaks() function already does that, I store the solved rectangles in the int ****pieces array

Comment: It's cheap enough. The 40x40 example takes ~0.1s on a reasonable desktop, ~0.5s for a random 50x50 bar.

Comment: @n.m. so would you care to post your solution pretty please? it certainly doesn't take 0.1s on 40x40 for me

Comment: @JohnDoe I'm sorry I don't post complete solutions to other people's homework assignments.